# ProForm not showing any fields

Tags: ee2

I'm using ProForm and just upgraded from 1.64 to 1.73. (Running EE 2.10.1.) Since the ProForm upgrade, none of my (visible) form fields show up. The labels for them appear, but absolutely no HTML for the fields themselves.

The hidden fields (including some custom ones) show up fine in the source.

We're using the simple form tag, so it shouldn't be a template issue.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

After testing some new fields (which worked) and comparing their MySQL data with that of the problem fields, I found that setting the MySQL field to 'NULL' in the proform_form_fields table made the fields work again. This unfortunately only worked for text fields - list fields (such as dropdowns) still did not work, but I was able to fix them by changing the "Style" properties to another type, saving the field, then changing the Style back to the desired format.

It appears upgrading from ProForm 1.63 didn't update the database the way it should have (might be my fault). However, all is working now. Hopefully this will help someone else if the same issue crops up for them! :)